# Stored procedure in Redshift not displaying anything

Tags: amazon-redshift

Hi I am trying to run the below stored procedure in Redshift. I am a newbie to Redshift stored proc.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE redshift_sample_sp()
AS $$
BEGIN
  RAISE INFO 'This is sample Redshift Stored Procedure';
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
;
```

The above query is completed succesfully. Now when I run the call procedure query, the procedure should display the info 'This is sample Redshift Stored Procedure', but it isn't displaying anything. It isn't giving any error also. The query runs succesfully but doesn't display anything.

```
call redshift_sample_sp();
```

Can somebody please help me out with this issue?

Comment: how are you running this? it appears on the log (ie not query output)

Comment: @JonScott I am running this on redshift query editor.

Comment: Yes i d onot see the log with that tool - try any sandard tool e.g. sqlworkbenchj or psql

Answer (score 1):

Try running this with `psql`.

A JDBC or ODBC tool that may redirect the output.

Answer (score 1):

You may not need this anymore but I found this while searching through similar use case.

Try running below query:

```sql
SELECT 
    query, recordtime, loglevel_text, trim(message) as message, aborted
FROM
    svl_stored_proc_messages 
ORDER BY 
    recordtime desc;
```

`message` column will show the output "display the info 'This is sample Redshift Stored Procedure'"